# Building a Live Chat Widget from Scratch using React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, widget, chat, live

I am trying to build a Live chat Widget from scratch using React.js and Node.js and was wondering if anyone knows of any resources or tutorials to make it?

I'm trying to do make one but I don't want to use any 3rd party apps because of the long-term cost (everyone has a free trial but it's paid monthly after that) and I would love the guided experience of building it.

Any information helps! Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 14):

I recommend you start with my blog article series about how to build a web widget.
This is a step-by-step complete tutorial with GitHub repositories.

You already know what a widget is, so you can start reading from part 2: [Web widgets (Part 2): Widget him!](https://chatscope.io/blog/web-widgets-part-2-widget-him/)
 - how to make a widget and load it to the website.

Part 3: [Web widgets (Part 3): API Cookbook](https://chatscope.io/blog/web-widgets-part-3-api-cookbook/)
 is about how to make an API for the widget.

The bonus part: [Web widgets (Bonus): Why iframe?](https://chatscope.io/blog/web-widgets-bonus-why-iframe/)
 is about the benefits of loading widgets into an iframe.

If you need UI components for your chat, please check my React chat library: https://github.com/chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react.

Additional useful library for managing chat state in react is: [React headless chat hook](https://github.com/chatscope/use-chat).

For message transport, you can use a plain websocket, but it's less painful to use [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) or [uWebsockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets)

Comment: Wow this helps so much, I was just going to jerry-rig it but this is huge! Thank you so much!

Comment: For the "Web Series (part 2) widget him!", after we do everything, are we supposed to still have an echo of whatever we type in?

Comment: Yes, you can check this by running both apps (loader and widget) on branches stage-2-3

Comment: @Shaneeyb If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @Antek You are super awsome.

Comment: These are great resources.