# What react or node js package is best for building chat functionality?

Tags: reactjs, express, chat, real-time

I'm building an app where users can chat with each other, so I want to know what packages are good for such needs.
Please only include free sources even if they have limited user count.

I'm using React and Express.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use socket.io. It provides real-time bi-directional communication and has official client libraries for most platforms.
[Socket.io Official Site](https://socket.io/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that one out

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to recommend you my two libraries:

React UI chat components: https://github.com/chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react

Headless chat hook (state management): https://github.com/chatscope/use-chat

Both are proven in production applications.

To communicate with the server, I recommend https://socket.io/

Also, this answer can be helpful: [Building a Live Chat Widget from Scratch using React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328150/building-a-live-chat-widget-from-scratch-using-react/71380037#71380037)

Comment: Thanks!! I'll see what suits me best