# Embedabble widget similar to intercom

Tags: javascript, iframe, widget

Hope you're all well! I’ve been trying to figure out how intercom built their widget. There really isn’t much on the internet that helps with this so I thought I’d ask one of you. Maybe you’ve worked on something like this in the past? Anyways, would love to know how something like an intercom widget is handled. I have the app built but I’d love to do exactly what intercom is doing by providing a script to the end user and load the widget in an iframe which also creates a dom inside that iframe? This is territory I've never worked on. Can anyone point me in the right direction? What I struggle with is do I go the iframe route, or actually inject javascript into the client. What is the best approach? Also would I create a separate project just to handle the widget, or do I include it in the same project? In my case I'm using solidjs.

Anyway, any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can look up open source intercom alternatives and see how it is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly the Intercom widget is made, but they are using an iframe and it's a good direction.

You can find almost everything about it in my answer to a similar question here: [Building a Live Chat Widget from Scratch using React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328150/building-a-live-chat-widget-from-scratch-using-react/71380037?noredirect=1#comment129957326_71380037)