# Script to embed HTML React project content on page

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, widget, embed

Scenario: My company wants to have a "content builder" on our event portal. We are a event manager. It is a project carried out with React and Next. How can I generate a code to embed each event in different pages? The idea is that event organizers embed their events on different web pages

Comment: This is beyond the scope of what is appropriate for stack overflow. iframes and/or module federation (webpack) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event is a classic example of a web widget, so you need to know how to build an embeddable widget.
Please check my answer to the follwing question: [Building a Live Chat Widget from Scratch using React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328150/building-a-live-chat-widget-from-scratch-using-react#71380037).

That question is about a chat widget, but the rules are the same regardless of the type of widget.